# Confusion regarding NSScanner (Scanner)

Tags: ios, swift, hex, nsscanner

I wrote an extension to return a UIColor from a hexadecimal string. Although it works, I don't quite understand the purpose of this piece of code

```
var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
Scanner(string: cleanHexStr).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)
```

Could you provide some insight/detailed understanding for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part creates a instance of `NSScanner` for the string `cleanHexString`. (Scanners are "attached" to a string.)

Then `scanHexInt32()` is executed on this scanner to get the integer value of the string representation. `rgbValue` is an out-argument. (The pointer to it is passed, what is the technique for out-arguments in C. `NSScanner` is an Objective-C class.)

Comment: So is it comparing the two values?
So after creating an instance of `Scanner` from `cleanHexString`, what exactly does `scanHexInt32` do?

Comment: As I said: It scans the attached string for a 32-bit integer value and returns the result in `rgbValue`. Nothing is compared. What for?

Comment: So it scans `cleanHexStr` for a 32-bit integer? For example, if i input the string `ffffff`, the value of `rbgValue` is **16777215** according to Xcode. I am not sure what that value means. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is the same value. 16777215 (or whatever) is the representation of the value in decimal notation, ffffff is the representation of the value in hexadecimal notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal